# How to run Sonatype Nexus repository on Eclipse Virgo server?

Tags: repository, maven, osgi, nexus, eclipse-virgo

I find it very weird I couldn't find anything useful googling for this so that's why I'm trying here: Could someone please explain to me how I can install Sonatype Nexus repository on Eclipse Virgo server?

I tried on my linux (ubuntu server) and windows machines but both gave me the error on  pasted down below when server started. (so I just dropped the war in the picked folder)

Thanks a lot in advance folks!

EDIT: Cause probably is related to: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonatype.nexus.web.NexusBooterListener

```
> [2011-01-12 19:57:52.155] Thread-3                     <WE0005E> Failed to start web bundle 'nexus-webapp-1.8.0.1' versi
on '0.0.0': consult the serviceability log for further details.
[2011-01-12 19:57:52.161] start-signalling-2           <DE0006E> Start failed for bundle 'nexus-webapp-1.8.0.1' version
'0.0.0'. org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.DeploymentException: Web application failed to start
        at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:129
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.ArtifactStateMonitor.onStarted(ArtifactStateMonitor.java:2
05)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.asyncStartSucceeded(AbstractInstal
lArtifact.java:273)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.access$0(AbstractInstallArtifact.j
ava:270)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact$StateMonitorSignal.signalSuccessfu
lCompletion(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:223)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker$1.run(BundleStartTracker.java:140)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.WebApplicationStartFailedException: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ServletContai
nerException: Web application at '/nexus-webapp-1.8.0.1' failed to start. Check the logs for more details.
        at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:107)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:120)
        ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ServletContainerException: Web application at '/nexus-webapp-1.8.0.1' failed
to start. Check the logs for more details.
        at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java
:123)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:90)
        ... 9 common frames omitted
```

I was able to filter a more specific error message in DEBUG log mode:

```
    INFO: Loading plexus configuration from: 'jndi:/localhost/nexus-webapp-1.8.0.1/WEB-INF/plexus.xml' 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.731]  2011-01-12 19:37:49 ERROR [rt-signalling-1] - o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.8.0~          - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonatype.nexus.web.NexusBooterListener 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.731]  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Nexus. 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.731]   at org.sonatype.nexus.web.NexusBooterListener.contextInitialized(NexusBooterListener.java:53) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.731]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4182) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.731]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4682) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:120) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:90) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:120) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.ArtifactStateMonitor.onStarted(ArtifactStateMonitor.java:205) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.asyncStartSucceeded(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:273) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.access$0(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:270) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact$StateMonitorSignal.signalSuccessfulCompletion(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:223) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker$1.run(BundleStartTracker.java:140) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]  Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]        role: org.sonatype.nexus.Nexus 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]    roleHint:  
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:238) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.732]   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:226) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.733]   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:220) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.733]   at org.sonatype.nexus.web.NexusBooterListener.contextInitialized(NexusBooterListener.java:43) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.733]   ... 16 more 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.733]  Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.733]   at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:350) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.733]   at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:234) 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.733]   ... 19 more 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.734]  2011-01-12 19:37:49 ERROR [rt-signalling-1] - o.a.c.c.StandardCon~          - Error listenerStart 
[2011-01-12 19:37:49.734]  2011-01-12 19:37:49 ERROR [rt-signalling-1] - o.a.c.c.StandardCon~          - Context [/nexus-webapp-1.8.0.1] startup failed due to previous errors 
[2011-01-12 19:37:50.044]            org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication            Failed to start web application at bundleContext path '/nexus-webapp-1.8.0.1' org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ServletContainerException: Web application at '/nexus-webapp-1.8.0.1' failed to start. Check the logs for more details.
```

Tried same Nexus version on Tomcat 6 -> had to remove serverlet lib from war -> tried same war once more on Virgo and I seemed to get a similar error message:

```
    2011-01-12 22:19:25 ERROR [rt-signalling-1] - o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.8.0~          - Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.sonatype.nexus.web.NexusBooterListener 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize Nexus. 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.sonatype.nexus.web.NexusBooterListener.contextInitialized(NexusBooterListener.java:53) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4182) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4682) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:120) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:90) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:120) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.ArtifactStateMonitor.onStarted(ArtifactStateMonitor.java:205) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.asyncStartSucceeded(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:273) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.access$0(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:270) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact$StateMonitorSignal.signalSuccessfulCompletion(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:223) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker$1.run(BundleStartTracker.java:140) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                        Caused by: org.codehaus.plexus.component.repository.exception.ComponentLookupException: java.util.NoSuchElementException 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                              role: org.sonatype.nexus.Nexus 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                          roleHint:  
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:238) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:226) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:220) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.sonatype.nexus.web.NexusBooterListener.contextInitialized(NexusBooterListener.java:43) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           ... 16 more 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                        Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at java.util.AbstractList$Itr.next(AbstractList.java:350) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.790] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           at org.codehaus.plexus.DefaultPlexusContainer.lookup(DefaultPlexusContainer.java:234) 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.791] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                           ... 19 more 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.791] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                        2011-01-12 22:19:25 ERROR [rt-signalling-1] - o.a.c.c.StandardCon~          - Error listenerStart 
[2011-01-12 22:19:25.791] start-signalling-1           System.out                                                        2011-01-12 22:19:25 ERROR [rt-signalling-1] - o.a.c.c.StandardCon~          - Context [/nexus-webapp-1.8.0.1] startup failed due to previous errors 
[2011-01-12 22:19:26.000] start-signalling-1           org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication            Failed to start web application at bundleContext path '/nexus-webapp-1.8.0.1' org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ServletContainerException: Web application at '/nexus-webapp-1.8.0.1' failed to start. Check the logs for more details.
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.ArtifactStateMonitor.onStarted(ArtifactStateMonitor.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.asyncStartSucceeded(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.access$0(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact$StateMonitorSignal.signalSuccessfulCompletion(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker$1.run(BundleStartTracker.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

[2011-01-12 22:19:26.002] Thread-3                     org.eclipse.virgo.medic.eventlog.default                         WE0005E Failed to start web bundle 'nexus-webapp-1.8.0.1' version '0.0.0': consult the serviceability log for further details. 
[2011-01-12 22:19:26.045] start-signalling-1           o.e.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.ArtifactStateMonitor   < public void org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.ArtifactStateMonitor.onStarted(org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.InstallArtifact) org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.deployer.core.DeploymentException: Web application failed to start
    at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:129)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.ArtifactStateMonitor.onStarted(ArtifactStateMonitor.java:205)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.asyncStartSucceeded(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:273)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.access$0(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact$StateMonitorSignal.signalSuccessfulCompletion(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.core.internal.BundleStartTracker$1.run(BundleStartTracker.java:140)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
Caused by: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.WebApplicationStartFailedException: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ServletContainerException: Web application at '/nexus-webapp-1.8.0.1' failed to start. Check the logs for more details.
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:107)
    at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:120)
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.eclipse.gemini.web.core.spi.ServletContainerException: Web application at '/nexus-webapp-1.8.0.1' failed to start. Check the logs for more details.
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:90)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:123)
    at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:90)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the record:
It appears that this is fixed using the latest version of Virgo + Nexus.